# Set new column on pandas dataframe with setitem

Tags: python, pandas

I have a nested dictionary (let's call it `dic`) which has nodes of different depths and where final nodes contain pandas dataframe. I am looking to provide a uniform way for accessing and setting values at any node (where "values" can be further dictionaries, dataframes, or columns in dataframes). To this end, I am using the following functions

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem, setitem

def get_item(path):
   return reduce(getitem, path, dic)

def set_item(path, value):
   reduce(lambda k,o,v=value: setitem(k,o,v), path, dic)
   return None
```

where `path` is specified by the user via a config file and is of the forms (assuming 3 levels depth) `[key1, key2, table_name, [column1, column2]]`.

This works fine, apart from the case when I try to set values to a new column in the dataframe in which case I get an error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Looking to understand why this is happening and how to resolve this.

For example,

```
dic = {}
dic['key1'] = {}
dic['key1']['key2'] = {} 
dic['key1']['key2']['table1'] = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [1,2,3], 'column2': [10,20,30]})
```

to get an item

```
get_item(['key1', 'key2', 'table1', ['column1']])
```

which returns

[image]

and to set an item

```
set_item(['key1', 'key2', 'table1', ['column3']], [100,200,300])
```

with expected output of

[image]

but this gives an error mentioned before.

The following works for setting columns

```
get_item(['key1', 'key2', 'table1'])['column3'] = [100,200,300]
```

but this does not offer a uniform solution (as in some cases the value can be another dictionary or a whole new dataframe).

**UPD1**

I think the issue is that `setitem` sets the value on each object in the iteration of the path, not just the final one, so I guess I need to split the final part of the path out and apply it to the final object.

The modified `set_item` now seems to do the job:

```
def set_item(path, value):
    if isinstance(path[-1], list):
        final_node = path[-1]
    else:
        final_node = [path[-1]]
    
    reduce(lambda k,o,v=value: setitem(k,o,v), final_node, get_item(path[:-1]))
    return None
```

Comment: please provide a [mre] of the data to demonstrate how you use the functions and the expected output

Comment: What is `table_name`? How do you call the functions and what do you expect as output?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you cannot always use `getitem` with a DataFrame (it can create a copy), you could use:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem, setitem

dic = {}
dic['key1'] = {}
dic['key1']['key2'] = {} 
dic['key1']['key2']['table1'] = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [1,2,3], 'column2': [10,20,30]})

def get_item(path):
   return reduce(getitem, path, dic)

def set_item(path, value):
   get_item(path[:-1]).loc[:, path[-1]] = value

print(get_item(['key1', 'key2', 'table1', ['column1', 'column2']]))
#    column1  column2
# 0        1       10
# 1        2       20
# 2        3       30

set_item(['key1', 'key2', 'table1', ['column3']], [100,200,300])

print(get_item(['key1', 'key2', 'table1']))
#    column1  column2  column3
# 0        1       10      100
# 1        2       20      200
# 2        3       30      300
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to read and reply.  While there are limitation to your proposed solution (as it doesn't allow for other values, e.g. dictionaries and dataframes, to be created), it helped me realize where I was going wrong.  Will update my post once I get the code working.  Thank you

Comment: @Confounded what you want is not fully clear, isn't your last object in the path always a DataFrame?

Comment: " I am looking to provide a uniform way for accessing and setting values at any node (where "values" can be further dictionaries, dataframes, or columns in dataframes)"

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was calling `setitem` with the full path and it was setting the value on the very first object in the path, rather than the last one, as I was expecting. Changing `set_item` function to first retrieve a pen-ultimate object with `get_item` and then applying `setitem` to the last object in the list only fixed the issue I was having.  See the last definition of `set_item` in the OP.